# kafka sarama lib how to know how many cosumers in a cosumergroup

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

I read the consumer group example in [here](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/master/examples/consumergroup/main.go)(provided by Shopify/sarama),
and I wonder that how would I know how many consumers are in a consumer group, are there any ways I could control the number of consumers?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

To list the consumers currently assigned to a group, you can use the kafka-consumer-groups .sh shell script. Assuming that $KAFKA_HOME is the root directory of your Kafka installation, you can do:

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe --group YOURGROUP --zookeeper ZOOKEEPER_HOST:PORT
```

If you want to list current groups, run the following command:

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --list --zookeeper ZOOKEEPER_HOST:PORT
```

Comment: Thanks. But I wondered can I list it or increase/decrease consumers using sarama?

Comment: May be you can have a look to  sarama/consumer_group_members.go (https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/master/consumer_group_members.go)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would take a look at it.

Comment: And may I ask that shouldn't it be --bootstrap-server instead of --zookeeper (I think it is used in consumer instead of consumergroup)?

Comment: Yes you're true for the new consumer API since Kafka 0.9. You can visit this link for further information about old and new consumer API: https://pavelmakhov.com/2017/03/useful-kafka-commands/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ClusterAdmin` interface in Sarama library.

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Shopify/sarama#ClusterAdmin